# Can't center div content on mobile view

Tags: html, css

[Won't Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRq2X.png) This is my first independent project.

On my website I have 3 cards that display centrally in-line on desktop view no problem.
On mobile view (Google Chrome Dev Tools) they position to the left of the screen.
I would like to center them.

```css
 

   @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      html,
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }
      .page2 {
   
      }
      .wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
      }
      .card {
        margin-right: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
      }
    }


    /*desktop display code below*/

    .page2 {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      transition: 0.4s;
      width: 300px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .wrap {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="page2">
      <h2>Blog</h2>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="card">
          <a href="welcome.html">
            <img class="card-img" src="str3.jpg">
          </a>
          <div class="card-text">
            <h3><a href="welcome.html" id="card-link">Welcome</a></h3>
            <p>Website Launch and my First Project</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <a href="blog.html">
            <img class="card-img" src="steve_roe_kyoto.jpg">
          </a>
          <div class="card-text">
            <h3><a href="blog.html" id="card-link"> Kyoto</a></h3>
            <p>My Recent Trip</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <a href="best.html">
            <img class="card-img" src="str4.jpg">
          </a>
          <div class="card-text">
            <h3><a href="best.html" id="card-link">Best of 2018</a></h3>
            <p>Neon Goodness from Last Year</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="umbrella_icon">
  <img src="umbrella-02.png">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="logo_footer">Steve Roe</div>
      <div class="footer_menu">
  <ul class="footer_menu_1">
    <li><a href="work_with_me.html">Work With Me</a></li>
    <li>
<a href="mailto:xxxxxxxxxxx.com">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

---

I've tried many different methods I just can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**

Display flex has sorted the problem and the content now appears centrally. But it has caused my footer to jump up the page > [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQzLl.png).

My HTML above has been updated to include the footer. What should I include in the CSS?

Comment: There's only 1 card in your html and no CSS for it. Post the full code please. Have you tried making the card div "display:block" with "margin: 0 auto" ?

Comment: Hi John, I've updated it all now - also I've not added anything to the .card in the media query as I'm not sure what the right thing is now.

Comment: If you have the desktop code below that media query in the stylesheet, as you do above, then the desktop styles are overriding the media query styles.  Put the desktop ones above.

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't know that, that's also sorted out some other issues I was having.

Comment: Glad you got it working. My answer below should work if you put the media query on the bottom. You don't need all that flexbox stuff just to center some divs.

Comment: Great your original suggestion now works. My footer is floating up the page now though if you know anything about that?

Comment: Before your <footer> put <div class = "clearfix"></div> and then in your stylesheet: 
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

Comment: Sadly couldn't get that working.

Comment: It's working now, just needed to add a wrapper div and it for some reason worked even without css properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the screen is small the all  are center in mobile screen otherwise that display normally

In the .cards class use the flexbox when the screen is small **425px** that *align in center.*

[Here is awesome guide on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_flexbox2_111516&utm_source=chromedev&utm_medium=yt-desc)

```css
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  width: 222px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .cards {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  .card {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="page2">



<h2>Blog</h2>

    <div class="cards">
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has worked but there has been another problem caused, perhaps by the flex box display. My footer now jumps up the page behind the image. I am going to update my original post for you to see.

Comment: Here is work fine output https://jsbin.com/nozebifumo and edit https://jsbin.com/nozebifumo/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite experienced, and I'm quite new to S.O., but I've had a similar problem in the past. I'm not sure this will work, but since this is HTML, one of my strong points of the moment, I'll share something that is pretty simple.

I'm not really sure how to write code becuz I'm new, but use this tag:

```html
<center>
  *Anything that goes in here will be center-aligned
</center>
```

And yea, it's called the center tag.

Hope this helps :P

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work either, but thanks for the suggestion, I will use that one in future projects.

Comment: I'll search for a better way if possible. I support.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the float in your media query. [Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkc84uo6/).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .card {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see that working on your fiddle but still isn't working in Dev Tools

Comment: Hi John I managed to get it working with the suggestion of using flex-box from another user. However, this has resulted in some other issues which I've updated my post with above.

Answer (score 0):

Better use Bootstrap for making form and div such that It can appear same as in case of mobile,tablet.
Learn more about Bootstrap at:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp